# Ошибка android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

Проблема в том, что эта ошибка появляется только на эмуляторе с версией андроида 4.4 (api 19), на двух телефонах (андроид 6.0 и 7.0) и эмуляторах с андроидом 5 (api 21) и выше  все прекрасно работает.
Вот собственно сама ошибка

```
    03-14 08:49:05.111 5066-5066/com.EViCo.revivemycar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback
03-14 08:49:05.115 5066-5066/com.EViCo.revivemycar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback
03-14 08:49:05.115 5066-5066/com.EViCo.revivemycar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback
03-14 08:49:05.115 5066-5066/com.EViCo.revivemycar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback
03-14 08:49:05.127 5066-5066/com.EViCo.revivemycar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.EViCo.revivemycar, PID: 5066
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.EViCo.revivemycar/com.EViCo.revivemycar.history.History}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.EViCo.revivemycar.history.History.onCreate(History.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.EViCo.revivemycar.history.History.onCreate(History.java:33) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020068
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:175)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:151)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.EViCo.revivemycar.history.History.onCreate(History.java:33) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

отсылает почему то сюда (`cursor = db.getAllData();` в `onCreate`)

```
    package com.EViCo.revivemycar.history;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.DataBase;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.MainActivity;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.R;

public class History extends AppCompatActivity
{
DataBase db;
Cursor cursor;
MyListCursorAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    db = new DataBase(this);
    db.open();
    cursor = db.getAllData();

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(History.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(History.this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    adapter = new MyListCursorAdapter(this, cursor);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(16));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{
    private int space;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space)
    {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        //добавить переданное кол-во пикселей отступа снизу
        outRect.bottom = space;
    }
}

public void delRec (long id)
{
    db.open();
    db.delRec(id);
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    adapter = new MyListCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    db = new DataBase(this);
    db.open();
    cursor = db.getAllData();
}
}
```

Comment: раз проблема с инфлейтом разметки, в вопрос нужно добавить эту разметку и где там строка 10 показать. из лога видно, что не может найти какой то ресурс с id 0x7f020068 и можно подумать, что в FAB бэкграунд не проходит

Comment: Векторные картинки используете в разметке?

Comment: а, все, спасибо за наводку, на `fab` стояла картинка загруженная, поставил картинку из стандартных ресурсов андроида и все заработало. Тем не менее я так и не понял в чем причина ошибки из за изображения на `fab`

Answer (score -1):

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

Может быть вызвана использованием векторного изображения в качестве фона Layout для API < 23, можно исправить ImageView во весь Layout вместо background.

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.